# ChartPrimaryYAxis LabelFormat without point

Tags: blazor-webassembly, syncfusion

`Syncfusion` `Charts`. For name Y => value display with point/comma. How i can display la value without point ?

```cs
<SfChart @ref=chart Width="auto" UseGroupingSeparator="true">
    <ChartPrimaryXAxis ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Category"></ChartPrimaryXAxis>
    <ChartPrimaryYAxis LabelFormat="{value}"></ChartPrimaryYAxis>
    ....
</SfChart>
```

[Number formatting](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-android/sfnumerictextbox/number-formatting) dosent worked `LabelFormat="n"`
[image]

*I noticed that, when we have the data more than 50 for example, the comma disappears, and if the value 1,2,3 there is always this comma*

`C#` => `wasm` => `Syncfusion`

Answer (score 0):

By setting the Interval to '1' in the ChartPrimaryYAxis property, you can avoid commas in the Y-axis value. Please find the attached sample and screenshot for your reference. Please check the below code snippet.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/XnameComma1916893260.zip

Screenshot:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s7ru.png)

Comment: [if i have more data it gives that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FADUt.png)

Comment: i can do some test ? for examle => //something like this ? if data less 10 add interval 1